# Best way to run multiple package.json build processes with a single Heroku dyno?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, heroku-cli, heroku-toolbelt

I have a Laravel application that is hosted on Heroku and serves multiple Javascript games from a single domain.  Everything is contained in a single Git repo.  The back-end application provides OAuth and other features that are shared by all of the games.  Each game is a standalone React app with its own separate node_modules folder.  The folder structure looks like this:

```
├── package.json
├── node_modules
└── games/
    └── checkers/
        ├── package.json
        └── node_modules
    └── chess/
        ├── package.json
        └── node_modules
    └── mahjongg/
        ├── package.json
        └── node_modules
└── public/
    ├── app-compiled.json
    └── games/
        └── checkers/
            └── app-compiled.js
        └── chess/
            └── app-compiled.js
        └── mahjongg/
            └── app-compiled.js
```

Each time I push a new version of this up to Heroku, I need to run a separate build command to compile the main web application and each of the separate React games.  Basically, this is what needs to happen:

```
npm install
npm run production
cd games/checkers
npm install
npm run production
cd ../chess
npm install
npm run production
cd ../mahjongg
npm install
npm run production
```

Those commands will compile the React games and place each one under `public/games/{slug}/app-compiled.js` where they can be served by the common web application.

I already tried adjusting the `heroku-postbuild` script in my main package.json file to look like this:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run production && cd games/checkers && npm install && npm run production && cd ../chess && npm install && npm run production && cd ../mahjongg && npm install && npm run production"
```

That actually works, but I'm worried that it might break at some point in the future as the build process gets bigger and more complex.  Is there a better, more supported way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Note that I am not open to the idea of running a separate Heroku dyno for each React app. I am eventually going to have about 30 games, and it would be cost-prohibitive to run each on a separate dyno.